# Lewis acid catalysis with BF3

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am a beginner of Lewis acids/bases reactions and found Lewis acid catalysis. There is an example, which is the opening of epoxide by an alkyne anion activated by $\ce{BF3OEt2}$:

[image]

1. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron_trifluoride_etherate), $\ce{BF3OEt2}$ serves as a source of $\ce{BF3}$. What are the factors to select a molecule that coordinates with the Lewis acid $\ce{BF3}$? For example, the same Wikipedia page also describes methanol and even propanol can be used (seems the same principle as the lone pair electron on $\ce{O}$ donates into empty p orbital in $\ce{B}$) Can I say *any* Lewis bases can coordinate with $\ce{BF3}$ for this Lewis acid catalysis?
2. Furthermore, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acid_catalysis#Mechanism):

> Lewis acid catalysis often involves binding of the catalyst to Lewis
> basic heteroatoms and withdrawing electron density.

So, just to confirm my understanding: The electronegativity of boron and fluorine differs greatly. When $\ce{BF3}$ forms an adduct to the oxygen atom in epoxide, the electron density of oxygen is drawn to the 3 fluorine atoms in $\ce{BF3}$, hence increasing the electrophilicity of oxygen atom. Therefore, rate of the attack by the nucleophile (alkyne anion) to open the epoxide is enhanced.

Comment: 1) Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.  2) Within reason, include pictures directly into the question because links to other sites than chemistry.se maye become dysfunctional.

Comment: 3)  As a general rule for the English language, if not used at the start of a phrase, the names of elements,  *are not* capitalized.  This equally applies to chemical names, too (e.g. iron chloride).